# Built-in user-id status is set to "Unassigned" in predefined user id view

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

If I apply a session-based custom segment defined as user-id status matches exactly "Unassigned" in the standard user-id view the segment is matched by several sessions / users.

Since the user id view should only encompass sessions where the user id is set this shouldn't be the case.
I can't find any proper documentation on how the built-in dimension user-id status gets populated, but I would assume that it is derived from the uid parameter sent with the server calls.

How can the value of dimension user-id status ever be "Unassigned" within the user id view?
[image: User ID Unassigned Segment within user-id view]

Taking the reversed segment defined as `status=Assigned` there are users that never had a userid assigned to them and are still in the user-id view.
[image]
How can user without an assigned userid be part of the user-id view?

Side note:

- Implemented via GTM
- Session Unification is active
- user-id status is a Google-intern dimension automatically created when setting up the userid feature.

Answer (score 1):

**`Unassigned` is not a value GA would set** ([when a value is not defined in GA it is set to `(not set)`](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en)), **so if it's there it's because someone set it.*

**Now with regards to your segment**, the question you are asking GA is:

- give me users who during ANY session had `status=Unassigned`
- this includes sessions prior to identification because Session Unification is active

**So anybody who had `status=Unassigned` at some point and then identified will match that segment.**

**If you want to know users who have `status=Unassigned` as their latest status** you want to make sure your custom dimension is set to [`User Scope`](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) and that you replace `Sessions Include` with `Users Include` in your filter.

Comment: User-id status is a built-in dimension. We can't control its behavior. It's automatically assigned either value "Assigned" or "Unassigned". When and how this gets populated is up to Google. The dimension appears once the user id view is implemented.

The only thing we're able to influence is setting the userid field, which is probably used by Google to derive user-id status.

Regarding the segment definition: Following your argument switching it to scope 'user'  and `status=Assigned` should yield 100% of users since a userid is required to be kept in the user id view. This is not the case.

Comment: Can you show me where the User-id status is from the list of built-in dimensions? https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

Comment: It's not listed in the dimension explorer. It still is created by default when creating a user id view. It's simply not documented by Google. Simply create a test account, go to settings under "tracking info" > "user id" create a new user id view and the dimension "user-id status" will be available in your GA property. No custom dimension needed.

Comment: Also, you are right on your response to the original question in general. I added a second case to indicate where I still see a problem with the collected data (or its representation in the GA backend).

Comment: You're right. `User-ID Status` is not documented in the list of dimensions but available in segments (not in reports though). I have applied the segment to a few User-ID views I have access to, it's always 100% (expected), and on non-User-ID views it's <100% (expected). Maybe it's an issue with the Segment preview. Do you have the same issue when you apply the segments in actual reports?

Comment: The problem is also present when actually applying the segment. I checked other accounts and the user-id status assigned coverage is also 100% (or very close). Hence, I assume that it is an issue with that specific implementation. It's hard to debug though as we have no control over user-id status.

Comment: Indeed hard to debug: you could create 3 custom dimensions (Client ID, User ID, Session ID or better Session Timestamp, see https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/13-useful-custom-dimensions-for-google-analytics/) and use the API to pull those 3 + 4 others (7-dimension limitation with API queries) such as browsers, OS, is returning, landing page etc.... and see if you can find patterns as to which sessions or hits are missing the user ID.

Comment: I already have the user id (user scope) and timestamps (hit scope) available as custom dimensions so I can see users where all sessions have user-id status set to Unassigned (using a custom report with custom dimenesion user id and the segment of user-id stauts equals Unassigned on user scope). I didn't find any patterns yet though.